# vertical Inclination of camera on android phone

Tags: android, android-camera, android-orientation

I use the function getRotationMatrix. Now I've the azimuth, pitch & roll of phone.
But I would like to have the inclination of camera.
The pitch is also influenced by the roll
an example of what I want:

1. the camera point to sky? angle -90°
2. the camera point in front? angle 0°
3. the camera point the floor? angle +90°

how can I do?

thanks in advance

Comment: http://www.whathaveyourtried.com ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this.. Get a reference to Camera object

```
    theCamera.setDisplayOrientation(90);
```

Comment: no.I used the camera as example.I want a number same a pitch but not corrupting by roll. Only the angle respect the x axis